# MAC address table in Cisco ASR1001

Tags: cisco, mac-address

This might seem silly but I can't find the MAC address table in my Cisco ASR1001. Look:

```
#sh mac?
macdb  

#sh macdb

                      Software MAC database
```

It must be another command, but I can't find it. Google didn't help.

Comment: More information would be helpful to give you the answer applying to your situation.  What features are you using on the router and what mac-addresses are you expecting to see?

Comment: I am interested to know about #show macdb as well. This command is not publicly documented.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's a router not a switch, so no MAC table is needed.

Instead, the ARP table--show ip arp--may be what you want.

Comment: Unsure why this is downvoted, since this is exactly the correct answer unless you are using bridge-domains/L2 transport as in Mike's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use `show bridge-domain [bridge-domain-number]`...

```
RTI-MPLS-SAB-01#show bridge-domain 4010
Bridge-domain 4010 (3 ports in all)
State: UP                    Mac learning: Enabled
Aging-Timer: 300 second(s)
    BDI4010  (up)
    GigabitEthernet0/0/4 service instance 4010
    vfi OCTEY neighbor 10.23.32.79 11
   AED MAC address    Policy  Tag       Age  Pseudoport
   0   0024.E64F.9A87 forward dynamic   292  GigabitEthernet0/0/4.EFP4010
   -   881D.F3D4.293F to_bdi  static    0    BDI4093
   0   0022.1A5F.166B forward dynamic   279  GigabitEthernet0/0/4.EFP4010
   1   FFFF.FFFF.FFFF flood   static    0    OLIST_PTR:0x2edad820
   -   0000.0007.AC01 to_bdi  static    0    BDI4010
   0   001B.2C3F.EDA8 forward dynamic   286  GigabitEthernet0/0/4.EFP4010
```

If they are secured... [`show bridge-domain [bridge-domain-number] mac security address`](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/cether/configuration/xe-3s/asr1000/ce-xe-3s-asr1000-book/ce-mac-addlmt-bdsin.html#GUID-6EF071BF-F18C-4093-80C6-FE2D01A50FC9)...

```
Router# show bridge-domain 730 mac security address
Port                  MAC Address       Type      Rem. Age(min)
Gi1/0/0 ServInst 1    0001.0001.0001    static    74      
Gi1/0/0 ServInst 1    0001.0001.0002    static    74      
Gi1/0/0 ServInst 1    0001.0001.aaaa    dynamic   74      
Gi1/0/0 ServInst 1    0001.0001.aaab    dynamic   74      
Gi1/0/0 ServInst 2    0002.0002.0002    static    -       
Gi1/0/0 ServInst 2    0002.0002.0003    static    -       
Gi1/0/0 ServInst 2    0002.0002.0004    static    -       
Gi1/0/0 ServInst 2    0002.0002.aaaa    dynamic   -       
Gi1/0/0 ServInst 2    0002.0002.bbbb    dynamic   -       
Gi1/0/0 ServInst 2    0002.0002.cccc    dynamic   -
```